# Rename batch files in windows

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

I have googled different ways to rename batch files, but I could not find a way to do it in the order I wish.
If anyone could help me I would be grateful.
I have the following files named:

```
NAME0000.txt
NAME0001.txt
NAME0002.txt
...
NAME0099.txt
```

For all these files I need to replace the 0 from the 2nd number from the left with a 1
Ex:

```
NAME0100.txt
NAME0101.txt
...
NAME0199.txt
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

not tested

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%a in (0;1;200) do (
  if %%a lss 10 set numb=000%%a
  if %%a gtr 10 if %%a lss 100 set numb=00%a
  if %%a gtr 100 if %%a lss 1000 set numb=0%a  
  set file_=NAME!numb!.txt
  if exist !file! (
    set /a numb2=numb+100
    ren NAME!numb!.txt NAME!numb2!.txt
  ) 
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Obviously I'm not very bright. Where can I set the path where those files are found? I placed the .bat file inside the folder where the files are but no change.

Comment: @Iuli add `pushd c:\somepath` at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is to just use string substitution:

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%A IN ( NAME00*.txt ) DO (
    SET OLD_FILENAME=%%A
    SET NEW_FILENAME=!OLD_FILENAME:NAME00=NAME01!
    REN !OLD_FILENAME! !NEW_FILENAME!
)
```

You need to run this script within the folder with the files you want to rename. Due to the nature of the `REN` commando, you can't just add some path to the fileselector `NAME00*.txt` in the `FOR` command. If it is a requirement for the script to work in arbitrary directories, please add this to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing some Google and found this third party tool which does awesome things in terms of your need -

**Bulk Rename Tool is a Lightweight but Powerful File Renaming Tool**

[image]

There’s no need to settle for overly simplistic file renaming tools as long as Bulk Rename Tool is around. It’s lightweight, insanely customizable, portable, and sure to make short work of any renaming task you throw at it.

Bulk Rename Tool is a great portable application (available as an installed version if you crave context menu integration) that blasts through file renaming tasks. The main panel is intimidatingly packed with toggles and variables you can alter; this isn’t a one-click solution by any means.

That said, once you get comfortable using the interface it’s lightening fast and extremely flexible. One tip that will save you an enormous amount of frustrating when you get started: make sure to highlight the files you want to change in the file preview window (located in the upper right corner) or else you won’t see the preview and won’t know if the changes you’re making in the control panel are yielding the file names you desire.

Hit up the link below to read more and grab a copy; Bulk Rename Tool is free, Windows only.

[Bulk Rename Tool](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php)